# Даты при сериализации и создании через setUp расходятся. Django

Tags: django, юнит-тесты, datetime

Пытаюсь протестировать приложение, но поле updated с датой обновления объекта. И из-за него появляется ошибка. Пытался ставить определенную дату обновления и не срабатывало, пытался ставить None, тоже не срабатывало, писал подобное `timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1)` и тоже не срабатывало, все равно поле updated автоматически само заполнялось с минимальными различиями во времени наверное сек или мс. Короче появляется такая ошибка:

```
    self.assertEqual(serializer_data, response.data.get('current_news'))
AssertionError: {'id'[141 chars]7.607389+06:00', 'updated': '2021-11-30T23:48:37.609387+06:00'} != {'id'[141 chars]7.607389+06:00', 'updated': '2021-11-30T23:48:37.614385+06:00'}
```

Вот setUp и сам тест:

```
class TestNews(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(username='testadmin', password='testpassword')
        self.test_news = News.objects.create(
            title='Testnews',
            slug='testnews',
            article='Intro test text',
            excerpt='Test News',
            important=True,
            lang='Ru',
            author=self.user,
            cover='test_image.jpg',
            banners=True,
            created=timezone.now(),
            updated=None
        )

    def test_news_detail(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('news_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.test_news.slug}))
        serializer_data = NewsDetailSerializer(self.test_news).data
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(serializer_data, response.data.get('current_news'))
```

Если я поле updated не заполняю вообще, то оно все равно автоматически заполняется.
Вот так выглядит поле в модели:
`updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлено')`

Comment: `auto_now=True` — вот именно поэтому оно автоматически заполняется

Comment: Понятно, но тогда странно, что даты различаются. Возможно из-за сигналов @andreymal

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем была проблема. Один сигнал заново сохранял, т.е. обновлял объект модели.

Поэтому, решением послужило - в начале теста обновлять базу данных через функцию `.refresh_from_db()`. Просто сделал так:

```
def test_news_detail(self):
    self.test_news.refresh_from_db()
    response = self.client.get(
        reverse('news_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.test_news.slug}))
    serializer_data = NewsDetailSerializer(self.test_news).data
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(serializer_data, response.data.get('current_news'))
```